# Eclipse separate consoles

Tags: java, eclipse, console

This question have been asked before, however I still don't seem to find a an answer that works for me.

Basically I'm creating a server/client Java program in Eclipse, and I would like to be able to have two separate consoles running both server and client programs. I tried using pin console but still getting same view on both consoles. Is it possible to run two programs on Eclipse simultaneously (given there are two main methods) ?

Comment: There's a little icon where you can choose which console to watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a launch group, and click run.
2. Check selected console. By default, the two consoles will be automatically switched. If you pin console, you just fix a console, and have to manually switch them.
   [image: Create launch group]
   [image: run client and server simultaneously]

Answer (score 1):

there is an option to go between console's: [image]